# Any smart database schema comparison tools?

Tags: windows, linux, database

I need a tool which can receive the schemas of a master and a target databases (generated by a tool e.g. `mysqldump -d --routines --triggers --events`) and generates an update script to update the target database.

```
+------------------------+                                             
|                        +--------------+                              
|    Master DB dump      |              |                              
|                        |     +--------v-------+                      
+------------------------+     |                |     +----------------+
                               | Migration Tool +----->Alter Statements|
                               |                |     +----------------+
                               +---------^------+                      
+------------------------+               |                             
|                        |               |                             
|   Target DB dump       +---------------+                             
+------------------------+
```

I've tried [Database Comparer v 6.2 Standalone Utility](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/index.asp) which is awesome. However it is not smart enough to detect column rename actions and simply drop and create a renamed column. The desired program, should ask user  to choose between rename or drop/create actions.

Comment: I'm considering putting a bounty here or asking a separate question, as my requirements are coming pretty close: I'd need something like this with the additional requirements of: open-source, Linux, works with MySQL and SQLite. Guess our requirements are not a match, but simply overlapping? Solutions for mine would match yours, but not vice-versa?

Comment: @Izzy think SQLite part of your requirements need a separate question. There is very little change that a single utility support both of those RDBMSs. I will be grateful to see you bounty here.

Comment: @Izzy Did you try the linked software? Perhaps there is some configs.

Comment: Afraid so, yes. And I was thinking either-or (if it wouldn't justify a separate Q I'd place a bounty here). And no, I cannot try the linked software: that's Windows only, I need it on Linux (and no, not emulated via Wine or whatever, too much overhead that). Moreover, it doesn't mention SQLite in its list of supported RDBMSs – which is what I'd need it for primarily.

Comment: Btw: a simple google-fu brought me to one of our sister-sites: [Comparing Sqlite databases](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/comparing-sqlite-databases). And despite the "SQLite" in its title, other RDBMSes are also covered, so you might want to give it a look, too! [SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com/) looks promising for both of us, btw :)

Comment: Also worth a look: [DB Solo](http://www.dbsolo.com/schema_comparison.html). And if it were available for Linux, [SQLite Diff](http://www.fmpromigrator.com/products/sqlite_diff/index.html) and [SQLite Compare Utility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220018/SQLite-Compare-Utility) would be nice for me …

Comment: @Izzy I will investigate on the links again. Most of apps need database connection instead of simple text schema file.

Comment: Confirmed. But that's all my Google-Fu brought up until now. I'd also prefer a tool working on "dump-files" instead – but better this than nothing :)

Comment: So had you any success yet – and maybe found something, or one of the above links proved to at least coming close?

Comment: @Izzy No, I have tested tens of tools without any satisfying result.

Comment: Sorry to hear. So this seems to be a "does not yet exist" thing :(